# reduceBykey Spark maintain order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, reduce

My input dataset looks like

```
id1, 10, v1
id2, 9, v2
id2, 34, v3
id1, 6, v4
id1, 12, v5
id2, 2, v6
```

and I want output

```
id1; 6,v4 | 10,v1 | 12,v5
id2; 2,v6 | 9,v2 | 34,v3
```

This is such that

```
id1: array[num(i),value(i)] where num(i) should be sorted
```

What I have tried:

- Get id and 2nd column as key, `sortByKey`, but since it's a string,
  sorting doesn't happen like a int, but as string
- Get 2nd column as key, `sortByKey`, then get id and key and 2nd
  column in value, `reduceByKey`. But in this case, while doing
  `reduceByKey`; order is not preserved. Even `groupByKey` is not preventing
  the order. Actually this is expected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any information about input type I assume it is `RDD[(String, Int, String)]`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
    ("id1", 10, "v1") :: ("id2", 9, "v2") ::
    ("id2", 34, "v3") :: ("id1", 6, "v4") :: 
    ("id1", 12, "v5") :: ("id2", 2, "v6") :: Nil)

rdd
  .map{case (id, x, y) => (id, (x, y))}
  .groupByKey
  .mapValues(iter => iter.toList.sortBy(_._1))
  .sortByKey() // Optional if you want id1 before id2
```

**Edit**:

To get an output you've described [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843391/reducebykey-spark-maintain-order/31845277#comment51634802_31845277) you can replace function passed to `mapValues` with something like this:

```
def process(iter: Iterable[(Int, String)]): String = {
  iter.toList
      .sortBy(_._1)
      .map{case (x, y) => s"$x,$y"}
      .mkString("|")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @zero323

Comment: Thanks a lot @zero323. The result rdd is  ""RDD[(String, List[(Int, String)])]""   Can you also tell me how to convert this RDD to "RDD[(String, String)]". So basically your output is ""(id1,List((6,v4), (10,v1), (12,v5)))"", but I need        ""(id1; 6,v4 | 10,v1 | 12,v5)""